# Adding a permanent number line to VIM OSX Terminal

Tags: macos, vim, terminal

I have come across a command for vim in osx terminal that allows you to view each line in a predetermined `.c` document, which is `:set number`.  I want to set this parameter to be on default each time a document is created or opened.

After doing a search I came across this: you can append `:set number` to `vi ~/.vimrc`

First, what is this file?  How do you access it, and how do I append such a command to it?

I've tried searching the vim docs for `.vimrc`, but it doesn't make much sense as it talks about there being "4 places for initialisations, etc..."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Note:** If you are on windows the `.vimrc` is called `_vimrc`

Your `.vimrc` file should be created inside your home directory (`~`). This is a script that is run everytime you start vim and should contain customizations to the editor such as the set number command. It allows you to customize and "program" vim. If you want `:set number` to be called every time you start vim, you should place it inside your vimrc to be run everytime vim starts.

Create a .vimrc (text) file with vim (or with any other text editor) in your home directory

```
$ cd ~
$ vim .vimrc
```

Then add this line:

```
set number
```

Notice there is no `:`. That is because this is not a command line command anymore and instead is executed as vimscript code.

The .vimrc file is useful for remapping keys to other commands, creating your own commands, turning on options like set number (there are many more) enabling plugins etc... For this reason, everyone has a different .vimrc file, which has been crafted as they use vim. I am often coding in vim, and decide it would be nice to have a command that you let me do something more efficiently, so I open up my .vimrc and add in something that would help me code faster.

As you use vim more and more, you will discover good optimizations to put in your .vimrc and the file will start to grow. You can google example vimrcs to see very cool settings that will help you code faster or better.

While in vim, use `:h vimrc` to see more information about it.

See [here](http://dougblack.io/words/a-good-vimrc.html) for a website about how to make a good vimrc.

Comment: Thanks - good answer, very informative.  I fully understand what the `vimrc` file is now.  I've just opened iTerm and edited the file and then pressed `:x` then I re-opened my `test.c` file and the numbers have stayed :-)  One thing I have noticed is that when I quit iTerm, it warns me that I am about to lose sessions.  Is this a normal alert, or am I not quitting vim correctly?

Comment: If you did not quit vim before you quit iterm, then that is one reason you are getting the popup. You should make sure you quit vim before closing the terminal window. If that is not the case, this depends on your iterm preferences under `iTerm -> Preferences -> Profiles -> Session`. There you can choose when you want to be prompted before exiting iterm.

Comment: Thanks - I've just followed your instructions in regards to iTerm, and it already seems to be set to `do not prompt me when quitting`.  So I quickly opened my `test.c` file and tried `:x` and then `:q` and iTerm still prompts me about closing sessions.

Comment: That's strange. Does `:x` actually exit vim? When you open iterm and close it right away does it give you this alert or is it only when you opened vim during the session? Is this a problem you are having since adding a `.vimrc`?

Answer (score 1):

`.vimrc` is Vim’s Runtime Configuration. It’s a Vim script that runs every time Vim starts up, so you can use it to run commands and configure the editor to your liking.

For `set number`, you would write in the `.vimrc`…

```
set number
```

See also `:help vimrc` if you haven’t already.