# Setting up Vim Color

Tags: vim, vi

I would like to have my Vim background black and foreground color white regardless of the language I am editing (eg bash, Python etc).

How can I save those settings permanently?

How can I do it in Vi/Vim?

Thanks
Rio

Comment: do you want to disable the syntax highlighting?

Comment: this question can be duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2975994/how-to-set-default-vim-colorscheme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to add this at the bottom of your .vimrc file:

```
syntax off
set nohlsearch
```

It basically removes all highlighting (also when searching).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know what your `.vimrc` file is, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25465029/adding-a-permanent-number-line-to-vim-osx-terminal/25465075#25465075) question.

To force vim to use black for background and white for foreground put these commands in your `.vimrc`

```
hi Normal ctermfg=white guifg=white ctermbg=black guibg=black
```

Your colorscheme may get in the way here, highlighting keywords with colors you don't want. If you want to disable that, just disable syntax highlighting.

To do that, add this line in your `.vimrc` along with the other one

```
syntax off
```

This may not work in the terminal, because your terminal may be also setting the background and foreground to different colors. If that is the case, you should look into changing your terminal colorscheme to white on black (it is one of the defaults usually).